# How to wrtie data to influxdb from golang array?

Tags: postgresql, go, influxdb

The problem is:
I have a database in PostgreSQL and I read all the data in Golang and make arrays from it. The question is: How can I take this arrays and put it in influxdb?

Comment: Do you have a code sample to paste ?

Comment: I posted it in answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"log"
_ "./pq"
"fmt"

)

type DbInfo struct {
id string
person_id int
timestamp int
age string
gender string
attention string
interest int
happines int
surprise int
anger int
disgust int
fear string
sadness int
neutrall string

}

var DBObject DbInfo
var DbArray []DbInfo




func main() {


db, err := sql.Open("****", "postgres://postgres:********/cam?
sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer db.Close()
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT avg(age), avg(id), avg(neutrall),avg(fear)  
 FROM public.stat`) //stringTimeDayAgoQuery )
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    //err := rows.Scan(&DBObject.id, &DBObject.person_id, 
 &DBObject.timestamp,&DBObject.age, 
 &DBObject.gender,&DBObject.attention,&DBObject.interest,&DBObject.happines, 

   &DBObject.surprise,&DBObject.anger,&DBObject.disgust,&DBObject.fear, 
   &DBObject.sadness,&DBObject.neutrall)
    err := rows.Scan(&DBObject.age,&DBObject.id,&DBObject.neutrall, 
   &DBObject.fear)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    DbArray = append(DbArray, DBObject)
}
fmt.Println(DbArray)
```

}
In this code. I read my data from postgreSQL. I read it as an array, now I want to import my output to Influxdb. Because I want to use Grafana and it doesn't work with postgresql.